# Codeiniter doesn't load session to other pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a project in `Codeigniter 3.1.4` and suddenly it is not loading session variables on other pages. I **configured to autoload the library in `autoload.php`**, but didn't work, I upgraded my CI to `3.1.5` but didn't work either.

I used **Native Session** too but no success.

I started a new project with one controller only for tests, but didn't work.

The code of test controller is below:

```php
<?php 

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->session->set_userdata('test', 'test1');

        echo $_SESSION['test'] . '<br>';
        echo anchor('home/test', 'Validate');
    }

    public function test() {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_SESSION);
    }
}
```

This is my config.php settings for Session and Cookie:

```php
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

I tried the **session driver as database**, but remained the same problem.

Comment: Add your session and cookie settings from **application/config/config.php ** to the question please.

Comment: DFriend, the code has been edited!

Comment: You need to set the session path. Put `$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();`.

Comment: Tpojka I did as you said but it didn't work. :(

Comment: can please update question, where you autoloaded the session library?

Comment: did you check the raw PHP sessions? Thanks.

Comment: load the session library to application/config/autoload.php file

Comment: The native php session doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

Load your session library in the controller if autoload not work:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->library->load('session');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->session->set_userdata('test', 'test1');
    }

    public function test() {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this->session->all_userdata()); //this will print the whole session array 
        print_r($this->session->userdata('test'));//this will print only session test variable
    }  
}
```

Comment: print_r($this->session->all_userdata());     Is this also gives empty array or not?

Answer (score 0):

Load the the codeignitor session library to application/config/autoload.php file

**autoload.php file**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

**home.php file** [controller]

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->session->set_userdata('test', 'test1');
    }

    public function test() {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this->session->userdata('test'));
    }

}
```

For more detail documentation follow this [link](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 0):

When using `$config['sess_driver'] = 'files'` then `$config['sess_save_path']` **must** be set to the absolute path to the sessions files folder. Session Files driver documentation [HERE](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver).

You might need to make your own directory and set the permissions for it. You should probably create it outside of the web server's "public" folders. On a WAMP installation the path to the public folder might look like this `C:\wamp\www\htdocs\` and Codeigniter's `index.php` is in that folder.

On an Linux based Apache system the path to the public folder might be `/var/www/htdocs/`.

You will want to create the sessions folder at the same level as `htdocs`. In other words, `/var/www/sessions/` or `C:\wamp\www\sessions\`. Permissions must be set appropriately!!!

CodeIgniter defines a constant - `FCPATH` - that is the path to the main `index.php` file. You can use it to construct the absolute path to your sessions folders.

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = substr(FCPATH, 0, strpos(FCPATH, 'htdocs/'))."sessions/");
```

The above assumes that `htdocs` is where `index.php` is located. Adjust the above code to match your folder structure. Assuming FCPATH is "/var/www/htdocs/" then `substr(...)` will return "/var/www/sessions/"